# How to use Toggle button jQuery in <div main..>

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I've been trying to hide/show button by using Toggle jQuery. But when I clicked the event didn't happen.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            var main = this.value;
            $("#" + main).slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

A **div**:

```
<div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
        <button>Toggle</button>
    </div>
```

Could anyone tell me what happened with these lines of code?

Comment: this object is the button, and this.value is undefined because button doesn't have value attribute, so your $("#" + main) will select nothing

Comment: Can you paste the HTML code for the items with id `main` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button does not have any value attribute, seem like you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#main").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I fixed it. But when the event was clicked, the **Toggle** button is hidden also. I have to refresh page and the button will appear again.

Comment: The button will be hidden because it is a child of the `main` div. If you want it to stay visible after being clicked, you need to move it out of the `main` div.

Comment: You need to move your button outside of `#main` div since your button is the child of your `#main` div so it will slide up as well